# php - Add Script Not working

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with my update script. Basically I enter values into textboxes and when I click on 'Add' these values get added to the database.

At the moment it is allowing me to enter intergers and these getting added to the database but when I try to add text it doesn't. The database field types are set to varchar(20) and this is my PHP code:

```
public function insert($tableName,$fieldArray,$fieldValues) {

    $pdo = new SQL();
    $dbh = $pdo->connect(Database::$serverIP, Database::$serverPort, Database::$dbName, Database::$user, Database::$pass);


    $this->sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tableName . " (".implode(',', $fieldArray).") VALUES (".implode(',', $fieldValues).")";

try {
        // Query
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare($this->sql);

        $stmt->execute();

        $count = $stmt->rowCount();

        echo $count.' row(s) inserted by SQL: '.$stmt->queryString;

        $stmt->closeCursor();

    }

    catch (PDOException $pe) {
        echo 'Error: ' .$pe->getMessage(). 'SQL: '.$stmt->queryString;
        die();
    }

    // Close connection
    $dbh = null;
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the sql query line to:

```
$this->sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tableName . " (`".implode('`, `', $fieldArray)."`) VALUES ('".implode("', '", $fieldValues) . "')";
```

The thing is you are not escaping strings with quotes. Like 'someText'

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose your fields into quotes.

Put the text as such

```
$text = "text"; //How you're doing it now
$text = "'text'"; //How you ought to (after sql escaping)
```

Or try this:

```
$this->sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tableName . " (`".implode('`,`', $fieldArray)."`) VALUES ('".implode("','", $fieldValues)."')";
```